# Not all states from top.sls will be applied in Saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I have an issue with my Saltstack and its top.sls. Unfortunately, not all my states from the top.sls will be applied the minion.

Here is my top.sls

```
  # master top.sls
base:
  'G@salt_control:true':
    - automount
    - chrony
    - columbus
    - db_db2
    - db_hana_tdi
    - db_maxdb
    - db_ora
    - db_ora-nonsap
    - db_sybase
    - dnsmasq
    - facts
    - grub
    - iptables_rule
    - lama_sync
    - ldap_hosts
    - ldap_services
    - logrotate
    - lvm
    - nsswitch
    - ntp
    - company_base
    - company_profile
    - pam_krb5
    - pam_ldap
    - postfix
    - rear    
    - resolv
    - rsyslog
    - salt-minion
    - sap_cc
    - sap_ci
    - sap_di
    - sap_trx
    - sap_wd
    - ssh
    - sssd
    - systemd
    - sysstat    
    - tsm    
    - userdef    
    - zypper    
  'G@cpuarch:ppc64le':
    - lpar2rrde
```

And if I run a highstate on the servers, not all states will be applied.
I can run any state on his own with no problem. For example the state "company_base" will not be applied by running a highstate. If I apply it alone, there is no problem.

The state will also displayed when I run "salt-call state.show_top".

Here is my Salt master config:

```
top_file_merging_strategy: same

fileserver_backend:
  - git
  - roots

state_top_saltenv: base
gitfs_remotes:
  - git@gitserver:team/salt.git:
    - saltenv:
      - base:
        - ref: master
      - dev:
        - ref: development
```

The grains (/etc/salt/grains) from my minion:

```
salt_control: true
```

Here is the content of the company_base:

```
{% from "company_base/map.jinja" import company_base with context %}

##
# add companyrpm signing key
company_rpm_signing_key:
  cmd.run:
    - name: rpm --import http://repo.company.lan/pub/RPM-GPG-KEY-COMPANY
    - unless: "rpm -q gpg-pubkey | grep -q gpg-pubkey-XXXXX-XXXXXX"

##
#  install company packages
company.scripts:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: company-dep-scripts
    - refresh: true

##
# install uc4
uc4_packages:
  pkg.installed:  
    - pkgs:
      - uc4

##
#  install default packages
default_base_packages:
  pkg.installed:  
    - pkgs:
{% set pkg_list = company_base.pkgs.get(grains.cpuarch) %}
{% for pkg in pkg_list %}
      - {{ pkg }}
{% endfor %}


getroot_sudo:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/sudoers.d/01-admin
    - contents: 
      - "# salt managed {{ sls }}"
      - "%basis   ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/su - admin"
      - "admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 440
```

The jinja map:

```
{% set company_base = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'Suse': {
        'pkgs': {
          'x86_64': [
            '"hostinfo"',
            '"tcpdump"',
            '"uc4"',
            '"getroot"',
            '"libX11-6-32bit"',
            '"company-dep-pa-001"',
            '"pmg_scripts"',
            '"company-dep-scripts"',
            '"pam_ssh"',
            '"psmisc"',
            '"telnet"',
            '"tcsh"',
            '"libgcc_s1"',
            '"libatomic1"',
          ],
          'ppc64le': [
            '"hostinfo"',
            '"tcpdump"',
            '"uc4"',
            '"getroot"',
            '"company-dep-pa-001"',
            '"pmg_scripts"',
            '"company-dep-scripts"',
            '"psmisc"',
            '"telnet"',
            '"tcsh"',
            '"libgcc_s1"',
            '"libatomic1"',
          ],
        },
    },
} ) %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the sanitized contents of `company_base`?

Comment: Do you get any errors or stacktraces when you run a highstate?

Comment: Hi Utah_Dave,
thanks for your reply. I just added the state code in the top posting.

Thank you.

Comment: while logged into the minion run `salt-call state.apply -l debug` and then post any stacktraces or errors. Thanks!

Comment: `salt-call state.highstate -l debug` might be better since it's an issue with the highstate no?

Comment: Is there a `top.sls` in your development branch, and does it have different contents?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's due to you having multiple environments defined via gitfs, but only `base` in your top file.

Given your config, try replacing `base:` with `{{ saltenv }}:` (in all branches), so it's mapped correctly and not merged with anything else.